# Forwarding the partial view's details to HttpPost method of a controller when button in partial view is clicked

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-4, view

Whenever following HttpGet method in controller is called it generates a partial view.

**Controller HttpGet Method**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddCredit(Guid creditBalanceId)
{
    var newCredit = new AddCredits()
    {
        CreditBalanceId = creditBalanceId
    };
    return PartialView(newCredit);
}
```

**View**

```
@model AdminPortal.Areas.Customer.Models.ViewModels.AddCredits


@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.CreditBalanceId)
<div class="input-small" id="credit">@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.CreditToAdd) </div>
@Html.ActionLink("Add","AddCredit", new {@class="btn"})
```

Whenever Add button is clicked in the partial view, I want it to be forwarded to **HttpPost method** of my controller with HiddenFor(**CreditBalanceId**) and **CreditToAdd** value

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCredit(AddCredits credits)
{
    _businessUnitRepository.AddCredits(credits);
    Information("Credits Successfully added!");
    return RedirectToAction("LicenseDetails");
}
```

**Question**

What changes do I need to make to my view so that when the button is clicked, i get forwarded to httppost method in controller with all the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Add", "AddCredit"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.CreditBalanceId)
    <div class="input-small" id="credit">@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.CreditToAdd) </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Add Credit</button>
}
```

Comment: hadn't tried that, but that was the option i was thanking about. Anyways thanks for saving my day again

Answer (score 1):

You could do it quite easily using something like Html.BeginForm and an  type of submit. This link is a pretty good example [MVC4 forms that save to entity framework models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408063/mvc4-forms-that-save-to-entity-framework-models)